# Cannot restore Jenkins security after disabling it in config.xml

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Yesterday, I locked myself out of jenkins while trying to configure ldap authentication, so I followed the instructions in the wiki and disabled security in the config.xml file via ssh. Now I want to get back to the normal jenkins security, but the possibility is not given under "Configure Jenkins" anymore. So I'm looking for a possibility to restore normal security through the config.xml.

Here is the relevant part of the current config.xml file:

```
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>1.477</version>
  <numExecutors>3</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None"/>
  ...
</hudson>
```

Has anyone an idea or maybe a valid part of a config.xml?

Comment: Please specify version of Jenkins you have. What does "Manage Jenkins" page who to you?

Comment: geez, if anyone with a port scanner can login remotely as root against your will (when useSecurity is true), then it is a CRITICAL vulnerability

Answer (score 7):

```
    <hudson>
      <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
      <version>2.130</version>
      <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
      <mode>NORMAL</mode>
      <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
      <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
        <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
      </authorizationStrategy>
      <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
        <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
        <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
      </securityRealm>
      ...
    </hudson>
```

I think you are looking for this as i am able to revert it back to my default config.xml **remember always make a backup of config before modifying it**.
just update those two tags authorizationStrategy & securityRealm and your are good to go. And for further reference check out
[jenkins_xml_reference](https://github.com/Verigreen/jenkins_with_docker/blob/master/docs/jenkins_xml_reference.md)

Comment: This should be the answer and `remember always make a backup` should be in bold

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to remove authorizationStrategy and securityRealm as per point #6:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

Answer (score 2):

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

Just change it to False. Then you can access the Jenkins Config from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you missed to set the following:

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding/replacing these three settings to config (`~/jenkins_home/config.xml`) did the trick (i.e. restored login page after it was gone for good when I changed the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>` and later restoring it to `true` did not restore status quo as expected):

```
      <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
      <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
        <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
      </authorizationStrategy>
```

*Side note: the lock-out happened in my case when I switched from BasicAuth to OAuth forgetting to add a new user to the internal users database managed by Jenkins (that would match the Github username:)*

Answer (score -1):

Even I faced the same issue but later I could figure it out the issue.

we need to remove `/` at the end of the below line.

```
<securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None"/>
```

it should be `<securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None">`

This has worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18039925)

Comment: Hi what you don't understand here

Comment: well make it clear to you. We need to replace with the below lines in the config.xml file
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
<securityRealm class="hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None">